# mypy lambda optional check

Tags: python, lambda, mypy

I noticed that mypy forgets type information when going inside the scope of a lambda. Below is a small example to explain:

```py
from typing import Optional, Callable

def wrapper(x: Callable[[], None]):
    x()

def foo(a: int):
    print(str(a))

a: Optional[int] = 0

if a is None:
    exit()

wrapper(lambda: foo(a))
```

Mypy complains about this snippet with error: `Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "None"; expected "int"`.
However, we already checked that a is not `None` before. This is surprisingly strange because if we were to call `foo(a)` directly (without the wrapper), it does work.
I'm using python 3.6.10 with mypy 0.740.

Is this intended behavior? And if so, how would you go about typing this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function foo returns None - is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, in this minimal example it is ok for `foo` to return None.

Comment: by the way your snippet runs for me on 3.8 without throwing error, outputting "0", also it seems in this case mypy behaves differently than classic python

Comment: Ah, I should've mentioned in the post that I'm using python 3.6.10 with mypy 0.740. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not due to `lambda`, but due to `a` being a closure. In short, the function is *technically* wrong even though the specific code cannot trigger the erroneous path.

As with similar issues of fixing closures in functions, forcing the name to be evaluated at definition provides valid typing:

```py
wrapper(lambda a=a: foo(a))
```

Note that [mypy cannot properly infer `lambda` types](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4226), so using `lambda` like this will still result in an error `Cannot infer type of lambda`.

---

Consider the completely equivalent named function:

```py
def l() -> None:
    # reveal_type(a) -> Union[builtins.int, None]
    return foo(a)
```

Notice how `a: Optional[int]` is visible here, not the reduced `a: int` after the `a is None` guard. So the issue is not from `lambda` instead of `def`.

The source of the problem is that both `l` and the `lambda` close over *all* values of `a`. Even though `a: None` has been rejected before defining `l`/`lambda`, it is valid to reset `a` later on.

```py
a: Optional[int]

if a is None: exit()

def l() -> None:
    # reveal_type(a) -> Union[builtins.int, None]
    return foo(a)

a = None
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got the following error: `error: Cannot infer type of lambda`

Comment: @MatthiasVerstraete I am afraid this is a shortcoming of MyPy. I have linked the respective issue.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the reference to the issue. This explains everything for me.